# Capture UIWebView screenshot of video?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm currently trying to take a screenshot of a video in my UIWebView.

It turns out black though. I'm wondering: 1) Are webview open GL objects? 2) should be trying to capture an OpenGL view? Has anyone solved this before?

Apple referene: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't rely on UIWebView utilizing GL, or any libraries at all.  Implementation details (especially in web frameworks) iterate quickly and remarkably.

Comment: I'm just trying to capture a screenshot of a youtube video, which is embedded in a UIWebView in this instance. Thanks

Comment: Hi , did you get the solution for this  ... please guide me also

Comment: Still looking for an answer for this as well...

Comment: did you get a solution?